# Speed of Videos in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, performance, frameworks, media-player

For some reason the *setcurrentPlayback* Method does not work. Thanks for any thoughts...

```
-(IBAction)abspielen:(id)sender {

  NSString *titleOfButton = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:titleOfButton ofType:@"mov"];
  NSURL *movieURL = [ NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

  MPMoviePlayerController *themovie = 
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: movieURL];   

  [themovie play];

  [themovie setCurrentPlaybackRate:2.f];  

  [themovie release];

  MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = 
     [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
  [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];

  [moviePlayer release];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the line

```
themovie.rate=2.f;
```

insted of `[themovie setCurrentPlaybackRate:2.f];` line
may be its work....

sometime in use of HTML blog,this method not work so just try given 1 line

May be it is useful to you....
:-)